# Get previous value in hierarchical pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have data like that

```
id   X  Y  Z
-----------------
0    1  2  10
0    1  2  20
0    1  3  30
0    1  4  40
0    2  2  50
0    2  2  60
0    2  2  70
0    2  3  80
0    2  3  90
0    2  3  100
0    2  3  110
0    2  4  120
```

I would like to calculate the previous value and 'index' of an X, Y pair. The end result should look like this

```
id   X  Y  Z    Z_previous   Z_index
---------------------------------------
0    1  2  10       0          0
0    1  2  20      10          1
0    1  3  30       0          0
0    1  4  40       0          0
0    2  2  50       0          0
0    2  2  60      50          1
0    2  2  70      60          2
0    2  3  80       0          0
0    2  3  90      80          1      
0    2  3  100     90          2
0    2  3  110    100          3
0    2  4  120      0          0
```

So fur, I did 3 new columns with shift

```
pf[Z_previous] = df.Z.shift(1)
pf[X_previous] = df.X.shift(1)
pf[Y_previous] = df.Y.shift(1)
```

Now I would do something like this

```
if X != X_previous || Y != Y_previous:
    Z_previous = 0
```

I am not sure how to do this with a data frame.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
# row index in a group
df2['index']=df.groupby(['X','Y']).cumcount()+1

# groupby to calculate aggregates
xf = df2.groupby(['X','Y']).agg(Z_previous=('Z', 'shift'),
                                Z_index = ('index', 'shift')).fillna(0)

# join the result
df2 = pd.concat([df2.drop('index', 1), xf], axis=1)

print(df2)

    id  X  Y    Z  Z_previous  Z_index
0    0  1  2   10         0.0      0.0
1    0  1  2   20        10.0      1.0
2    0  1  3   30         0.0      0.0
3    0  1  4   40         0.0      0.0
4    0  2  2   50         0.0      0.0
5    0  2  2   60        50.0      1.0
6    0  2  2   70        60.0      2.0
7    0  2  3   80         0.0      0.0
8    0  2  3   90        80.0      1.0
9    0  2  3  100        90.0      2.0
10   0  2  3  110       100.0      3.0
11   0  2  4  120         0.0      0.0
```